# How to store data in an authentication session

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to store some authentication specific data in session, which is destroyed once a user is logged out.

I've tried this:

```
if ($didLogin) {
      // Save the client id in session
      $request->session()->put('client_id', $input['client_id']);

      return redirect()->intended('/');
    }
```

Which works, but does not remove the data once the user logs out or is logged out automatically.

I've read the docs but it doesn't seem to be clear on this, I just need some additional data to be supplied in the login process.

Comment: You can create a Listener for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout` event and clear the session in this Listener but i'm not sure if this works when the user is logout automatically

Answer (score 0):

Flush user session on logout

Put this method in your controller e.g UserController
And called this method when user click on logout button e.g. user/logout

So that on user logout all session data was flushed out..

```
//User Logout
public function getLogout()
{
  Session::flush();
  $this->auth->logout();
  return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Does this cover when _the user is logged out automatically_?

Comment: Where am I supposed to put this function? I feel like you should be a bit more descriptive instead of just posting 5 words and then a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You have authentication system, So When a user wants to logout it hit the following method, Below we have `Session::flush();`, Which will destroy session data.

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Now you have an empty `client_id`. You can check it like,

```
if ($request->session()->has('client_id')) {
    return 'Data exists';
}
return 'Data does not exists';
```